# Zoom SDK + Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, zoom-sdk, d-pad

I know that Zoom SDK officially not supporting Android TVs. But the apps with an integrated Zoom SDK can run on TV devices and it is even normally handled by a DPAD.

Except of one issue. When you start a meeting, the app shows you the bubble with *"Call via Device Audio"* or *"Dial in"* and does not respond to any of the DPAD controls input. You can not select anything with remote controller. It seems like the meeting screen is not focused.

Only after you press *"Call via Device Audio"* or *"Dial in"* by mouse the UI gets focus and the DPAD controls start working as expected.

Is there any way to fix this to make Zoom fully compatible with the TV devices which do not support touch/mouse input?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @anmig, Did you find any solution to work Zoom on Android TV?